# Updating both srcset and src

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

If I am using the function below. Would this be the correct way to update both the src and the srcset attributes?

```
<img id="Image" srcset="img/my-large-image.jpg x2" src="img/my-image.jpg" width="500">

$("#Image").one("load", function() {
    //code
}).attr("src", "img/my-new-image.jpg").attr("srcset", "img/my-new-large-image.jpg x2");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

```js
$("#Image").one("load", function() {
    //code
}).attr("src", "img/my-new-image.jpg").attr("srcset", "img/my-new-large-image.jpg x2");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="Image" srcset="img/my-large-image.jpg x2" src="img/my-image.jpg" width="500">
```